# How to force XMLHttpRequest to be synchronous - ("GET",addrServletURL,false) is not synchronous 100%

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

`enter code here`Below is my code 
When connecting with IE browser the client will wait the server response  in order to handle the data parsing   - the server takes some time to send back the result to the client  because  it’s calling an external system in order to get the data 
So to resume I have no problem when IE is my browser

But indeed when my  browser is Safari  in  the below code (please see my full code )the alert will be shown after a while which means the client is not waiting the server response and this creates a potential problem for me .
My question how I can force the client to wait the server response when using XMLHttpRequest with Safri

```
       xmlDoc= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlDoc.open("GET",addrServletURL,false);
        xmlDoc.send("");
        // Check results
        if ((xmlDoc == null) ||(xmlDoc.responseXML == null)){
                                 alert(pageDefs.msg["ADDRESS_HELP_NOT_AVAILABLE"]);
           return result;
                      }
        nodes=xmlDoc.responseXML.documentElement.childNodes;
        topElement=xmlDoc.responseXML.documentElement.nodeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the synchronous request approach tends not to work stable across browsers.

If you want to parse the response once it has fully loaded, use an asynchronous request, bind a function to the `onreadystatechange` property and check `readyState == 4` (i.e. fully loaded) then process it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do synchronous transfers? You could use a callback and display a message to the users the request is not yet done.

```
xmlDoc.onstatechange = function(){
  if ( xmlDoc.readyState == 4 && xmlDoc.responseXML ){
    // Execute important other code here. responseXML is loaded.

    // Check results
    if ((xmlDoc == null) ||(xmlDoc.responseXML == null)){
      alert(pageDefs.msg["ADDRESS_HELP_NOT_AVAILABLE"]);
      return callback(result);
    }
    nodes=xmlDoc.responseXML.documentElement.childNodes;
    topElement=xmlDoc.responseXML.documentElement.nodeName;
  }
};
```

wrap this in

```
doStuff(callback){
  // xmldoc code here.
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer 
I’ve got your  idea  so I have to refactor my code logic   and this is the only that I have  I think 

Why I need it synchronous because my code was written  in procedural way   for IE and now I’m making it compatible with Safari 

I will try what you have suggest and hope it will work